# Android SQLite rawquery parameters

Tags: android, sqlite

How can i pass intger to a rawquery in sqlite for android. 
Here its not taking g and s into query. Please guide.

```
    int g, s;

    Cursor cur3 = database2.rawQuery("select max(UnixTimeStamp) from Quote where EmoticonID=%d and SubCategoryID=%d" ,new String [] {g,s});
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

All parameter places should be designated with ?. The parameters to the query are always string nontheless, so nothing special about the integers. This should work for you:

```
Cursor cur3 = database2.rawQuery("select max(UnixTimeStamp) from Quote where EmoticonID=? and SubCategoryID=?" ,new String [] {String.valueOf(g),String.valueOf(s)});
```

Answer (score -3):

Parameter in your query needs to be string so please convert these parameters into string and write your query as follows.

Use `String.valueOf();`

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(SELECT max(UnixTimeStamp) 
                       FROM Quote 
                       WHERE EmoticonID ='"+d+"' AND SubCategoryID ='"+ s +"'");
```

Thanks

Comment: This allows for sql injections.

Answer (score -6):

```
Cursor cur3 = database2.rawQuery("select max(UnixTimeStamp) from Quote where EmoticonID="
                                 + g + " and SubCategoryID = " + s + " ");
```

Comment: Broken on multiple levels, but advocating a solution significantly worse than what the OP asked is irresponsible. Please read up on SQL injection.