# Special characters in LIKE with SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, special-characters, sql-like

I want to search in DB for like **$!(%&'^%$&'%^&&'^'%'**

I tried following queries but still error is shown:

```
select * from data
where data1 LIKE \'$!(%&'^%$&'%^&&'^'%'\'

select * from data
where data1 LIKE '$!(%&'^%$&'%^&&'^'%''

select * from data
where data1 LIKE '$!(%&\'^%$&\'%^&&\'^\'%\''

select * from data
where data1 LIKE '$!(%&\\'^%$&\\'%^&&\\'^\\'%\\''

select * from data
where data1 LIKE '$!(%&\'^%$&\'%^&&\'^\'%\'' ESCAPE '\'
```

Comment: using sql parameters will make your life a lot easier.

Comment: Can you provide any example?

Comment: there are questions similar to yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9341204/android-sqlite-rawquery-parameters

Comment: concatenating strings with sql commands are not only tedious but also dangerous. read up on sql injection.

Comment: @MartinOngtangco While this is a good suggestion for dealing with the escape characters, I don't think SQL injections apply in this example since there are no foreign variables.

Comment: @Sam, true... but that was a generic suggestion in dealing with in-line sql commands. thanks for raising that, though.

Comment: Please show an example for a value that would match.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all.

I got the answer.

```
String originalString = "$!(%&'^%$&'%^&&'^'%'";
String convertedString = DatabaseUtils.sqlEscapeString(num);
```

Pass this convertedString as parameter to query.

Answer (score 0):

From [SQLite's documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html):

> A single quote within the string can be encoded by putting two single quotes in a row

So double up your single quotes, like this:

```
select * from data
where data1 LIKE "$!(%&''^%$&''%^&&''^''%''"
```

But honestly, I had to do a little more reading to see if I missed any other special characters...

Comment: Thank you for reply. But this didn't work for me. It doesn't give any error. But results in nothing.

Comment: Have you checked if you table has any data that matches this complex pattern?

Comment: Since this is an un-orthodox almost RegEx pattern, what data are you trying to match?

Comment: Yes. I have this data. Basically, I have such entry in DB and I am trying to search and display it.

Comment: Ok, but can you shown some samples of what you are trying to match? SQLite doesn't use RegEx, only the two wildcards `%` and `_`.