# Insert a String containing an apostrophe (sqlite)

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Is there a way to save strings that contain an apostrophe into an sqlite database?

(I have an app that saves the names of all installed apps on your device and ran into an error while saving "Dood's Music Streamer")

Comment: Use parameter binding: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9341246/49489

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a compiled statement and bind the `String` parameter.

```
SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
SQLiteStatement stmt = db.compileStatement("INSERT INTO FOO (NAME) VALUES (?)");
stmt.bindString(1, "Dood's Music Streamer");
stmt.execute();
```

Comment: Thanks @Elliott, this looks like a easy solution. I'll try this and let you know if it worked. But I do have one question: What's the first parrameter in ".bindString"?

Comment: @user3557677 It's the corresponding ? mark. So, if you had VALUES(?,?) you would `bindString(1, "foo")` and `bindString(2, "bar")`

Comment: Yes! It works, although I had to insert three Strings, so I used **.bindAllArgsAsStrings** and had to change values(?) to values(?,?,?). I've accepted your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with sqlite, but it might need an escape character similar to Java and C++, for example Dood\'s Music Streamer