# How to get sum of column in SqlLite using where condition?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

My code is

```
Button.setOnClickListener(new    View.OnClickListener() 
    { 
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) { 
            int cv; 
            String getmont="",getyear="";
            getmont=year.getText().toString();
            getyear= (String) sid.getSelectedItem(); 
            SQLiteDatabase db;
            db = openOrCreateDatabase("monthapp", MODE_PRIVATE, null); 
            curtop = db.rawQuery("SELECT    SUM(currentpaid)FROM monthvaluesOrgin WHERE curmonth='" + getmont + "' AND curyear='" + getyear + "'", null);
            if (curtop.moveToNext() ) { 
                cv=curtop.getInt(0);      
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),cv,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
            } 
        }
     });
```

How to print/ toast the sum value?
It always shows error `EofException`.

My app shows "unfortunately your app has stopped".

Please give me a solution!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You code might be at risk of [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection). You should use query parameters.

Comment: I'm in a beginner level please show how to do that

Comment: Here's an example https://stackoverflow.com/a/9341246/3072566

Comment: Thanks but how to print the value

Comment: Where exactly does the crash happen?

Comment: When toast the value
Or button presses

Comment: An EOF does not make sense at that line. Are you sure that an EOFException is shown in logcat?

Comment: Yes but also tried in try catch block doesn't works

Comment: What exception did you try to catch?

Comment: EofException EOF in catch
I tried when the error occurred

Comment: So it means it's not an EOF if you could not catch it. Can you post the full logcat crash log

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong signature for [`makeText`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#makeText(android.content.Context,%20int,%20int)). Because `cv` is an `int` the compiler think you are trying to pass a resource id and since your sum is unlikely to be a valid string ID your app crashes because `makeText` cannot find that that number in the string resources. Try to use [`valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(int)) to convert `cv` to a string like this :

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),String.valueOf(cv),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Which means you sum right now is 0. Check your data, your table might be empty

Comment: Are you sure it has values that satisfy your conditions?

Comment: Yes ofcourse it does is that possible to send snapshot via email

Comment: From where does `openOrCreateDatabase` come? I can't find a method with that signature.

Comment: I'm using this instead of using database helper 
It may not be right way 
But results always shows 0

Comment: And what's inside of that?