# How to add a variable to a table in SQLite?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

What I am trying to do is store an ArrayList in my SQL database, and I've used this code to do so:

```
try {
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.openOrCreateDatabase("arrayList", MODE_PRIVATE, null);

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String inputString = gson.toJson(itemOne);

        Log.i("InputString", inputString);

        database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS savedTasks(item VARCHAR)");

        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put("item", inputString);
        database.insert("savedTasks", null, cv);

        Cursor resultSet = database.rawQuery("Select * from savedTasks", null);
        resultSet.moveToFirst();

        String getData;

        if(resultSet.moveToNext()) {
            getData = resultSet.getString(0);

            Type type = new TypeToken<String>() {}.getType();

            arrayLists.add(gson.fromJson(getData, type));
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        Log.i("ArrayLists", String.valueOf(arrayLists));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I keep getting an error, *E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such column: inputString.*

The commented code is from the answer to this post. I get the same error with or without it. Googling this has yielded no usable answers or examples. I am writing this in Android Studio (java).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android SQLite rawquery parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9341204/android-sqlite-rawquery-parameters)

Comment: @Dai no, I need a way to add a string variable to a database, not find it. Unless I'm misunderstanding what's going on in that post?

Answer (score 1):

The recommended method to insert new rows to the table is `insert()` with `ContentValues`:

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put("item", variable);
database.insert("tablename", null, cv);
```

Change `"tablename"` to the actual name of your table.

Comment: I added that, but I still get the same error. You can see what I did in the original post — as far as I can tell, that code isn't giving me any errors, but I might have written it the wrong way.

Comment: @easybeak You get the error *no such column: inputString* with your code. Remove `database.execSQL("INSERT INTO savedTasks VALUES (inputString)");` and uncomment the 3 lines above it.

Comment: I no longer get an error, but the contents of the database haven't changed. The end result is still just a string containing "inputString".

Comment: What is the value of the variable inputString? I see that you assign gson.toJson(itemOne) to it.

Comment: It's an ArrayList that's been converted to a string: `["This","Is"]`

Comment: @easybeak then this line: `cv.put("item", inputString);` inserts `["This","Is"]` in the table. If you see `inputString` in the table this means that you are not using my code as it is.

Comment: @easybeak uninstall the app from the device so the db is deleted and rerun to recreate it. Also remove `resultSet.moveToFirst();` from your code.

Comment: I did change "item" to "task" because I assumed that was meant to be the name of the column. When I change it back to "item" like in the original code, I get an error that says there is no column in my table called "item" even if I give the column in my table that name. That's the only change I made.

Comment: @easybeak see my previous comment. You must recreate the table and use correctly the table and column names.

Comment: I did delete and reinstall the app. As far as I can tell, all the names are correct and my code matches what you gave me. Is there something I should replace `resultSet.moveToFirst();` with? When I removed that, it stopped retrieving the data altogether.

Comment: And I now have this error: `W/System.err: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $`

Comment: @easybeak this error has nothing to do with the database and how you access it. You must debug your code to find where and why you get this error.